# How does an Android EditText (TextView) draw the blinking cursor?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I'm making my own Mongolian vertical script `TextView` (and `EditText`) from scratch by extending `View`. I'm trying to understand how the blinking cursor is implemented in the [Android `TextView` source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java). It seems to be handled by an `mEditor` instance of the [`Editor` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/37960c7/core/java/android/widget/Editor.java). In that class I found a `drawCursor` method:

```
private void drawCursor(Canvas canvas, int cursorOffsetVertical) {
    final boolean translate = cursorOffsetVertical != 0;
    if (translate) canvas.translate(0, cursorOffsetVertical);
    for (int i = 0; i < mCursorCount; i++) {
        mCursorDrawable[i].draw(canvas);
    }
    if (translate) canvas.translate(0, -cursorOffsetVertical);
}
```

Apparently, the cursor itself is a [`Drawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) of some type.

So I am finding pieces, but I can't see the forest through the trees. Could someone who understands this better than me tell me in plain English how the blinking cursor works?

Here are some specific points I don't really understand:

- The cursor's relationship to the `TextView` (or `EditText`), `Layout`, `Editor`, and `Drawable`.
- Every time the cursor blinks, is all the text being redrawn or only the cursor region?

**Note:**

The accepted answer answers my question as I asked it. However, I would be glad to accept a different answer if anyone can add a more canonical one that explains things in more detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `EditText` is just editable `TextView`, `Layout` is used for measurements, calculation, where and how the text will laid out. `Drawable` is there just to hold the look of the cursor, later being drawn on the `Canvas`.
2. Only cursor `Path` is [invalidated](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L5237).

Blinking basically is recursive `Runnable` that a `Handler` executes every 500ms (guessing), in on-off fashion, and it is rescheduled while `EditText` has focus. This also can be achieved by looping `ValueAnimator` of int, where the cursor drawable alpha will be toggled between 0 and 255.

Comment: The trick to link to specific code lines in GitHub it worth an upvote in itself!

Answer (score 2):

You can find [this method in the `TextView` class](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L7977):

```
public void setCursorVisible(boolean visible) {

    if (visible && mEditor == null) return; // visible is the default value with no edit data
    createEditorIfNeeded();
    if (mEditor.mCursorVisible != visible) {
        mEditor.mCursorVisible = visible;
        invalidate();

        mEditor.makeBlink();

        // InsertionPointCursorController depends on mCursorVisible
        mEditor.prepareCursorControllers();
    }
}
```